# create method in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to understand this line of code in Rspec.

```
create(:practice, creator: create(:physician, password: "password123", password_confirmation: "password123" ), phone: "+1 (555) 555-5554", office: "+1 (555) 555-5555", clinic_key: "abc123")
```

What is this **create** function. It is not built in rails or ruby function. Do we have its documentation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like `create` is called from `FactoryBot`.

Usually you need to create object like `FactoryBot.create(:user)` but if you configure factory bot

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

(see [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#configure-your-test-suite)) you can omit `FactoryBot` and use short variant `create(:user)`.

So your code creates factory `practice` with creator which is created by another factory `physician`.